# How do i switch from elementaryOS to Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, ubuntu, usb

Okay, so ill cut this short.
I had switched from Windows 10 to elementaryOS because windows had gotten laggy. After switching, i realized there weren't a lot of games and couldn't use Wine so Ubuntu was my option. I installed Ubuntu on a USB with UNetbootin and tried to boot the USB drive. And the roadblock. When i manually booted via boot menu, the computer jumps right in to elementaryOS. I'm just looking for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use unetbootin unless a distro specifically requests it. On Linux, your best bet is to just use DD (google how to do it with an iso), or use gnome disk utility (google it as well), or BalenaEtcher. On Windows, use Rufus, or again, use whatever method the install guide for the Distro recommends.

Secondly, Elementary is based on Ubuntu LTS. Anything that works on Ubuntu, works on eOS (usually except the occasional bugs). I've personally had no issues installing Wine, Lutris, and Steam on eOS. Both Lutris and Wine has install guides how to do it.

Comment: I used Startup Disk Creator (installed via Terminal) and it seems like it worked, but it jumps into elementaryOS, even with manually booting. I want to try/install Ubuntu to play Minecraft and i like the Ubuntu interface more because it looks a bit like the Windows 10 interface.

Comment: Are you sure you're picking the USB stikc in the boot order of your BIOS? Might also be the flash drive that's borked. Try another, or create a CD/DVD instead.

Comment: Im pretty sure I am, because Startup Disk Creator, Etcher, ISO burner and boot menu says its name as "Generic USB Device" and its the only removable drive i have plugged in. And, I dont have another USB Drive, maybe ill buy one tomorrow

Comment: Third option is BIOS vs UEFI. Which one do you have? I'm not sure how Startup Disk Creator does it, but if the created media is for UEFI, and you're BIOS, that might be why. UEFI usually supports both, but BIOS doesn't support UEFI.

Comment: I have BIOS, the created media is Ubuntu 19.10, i dont know if its UEFI or BIOS.

Comment: Honestly speaking, all I can think is the media gets made wrong, or the stick is just done for. One last ditch effort, if you have a working Windows 7 or higher installation, is to go use Rufus, and make sure it's set for BIOS. But, it honestly seems most like that your USB is broken.

Comment: I mean, I lost a 16GB USB in my room, and the one i have is 4GB (possibly broken?)and i've looked everywhere and ill probably find it in a few minutes. If i dont, my mom has a laptop with windows 10 i could use, but it'd make her computer slow.

Comment: Come back here once you've tested another usb stick. I'll check periodically throughtout the day. :P

Comment: Ill come back when i find my usb stick i lost (which i used for installing eOS) or when i buy another usb stick

Comment: Couldn't find my old USB stick, i've been looking for it this whole hour.

Comment: Well, there's nothing I can do to help with that. Until you try a new USB, there's not much for any of us to help with. It's not an actual Elementary issue. :p

Comment: Ill comment again if i get a new USB. Until then, Stabsy.

Comment: One thing it COULD be. https://superuser.com/questions/602123/cant-boot-from-usb-even-with-bios-set-correctly One of them comments that the BIOS doesn't register the USB stick as a "removable drive", but as an actual harddrive. Something you could look into.

Comment: There's one thing I forgot to try, I didn't try booting from the GRUB menu. I'll look into that later.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're problem is about the boot media, not about elementary.

Don't use UNetbootin, which usually fails. Use [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) which usually is better.

Either way, elementaryOS is based on Ubuntu, so if anything runs on Ubuntu it runs on elementary. I use elementaryOS and play a lot of games in Steam via Proton (a utility developed by Valve to run games via Wine) and I'm very happy.

Comment: First time it said isolinux.bin was corrupt. I downloaded another version and then it started happening again, PC started booting to elementaryOS instead. I tried downloading the same version again, and yes i used Etcher.

Answer (score 0):

I'll echo babel's comments.  I haven't found anything in a debian or ubuntu package that doesn't install in elementary.  I think wine is even in the App Center.

That being said, I did a lot of distro hopping before settling on elementary OS and I often find that nothing will work.  Just a few days ago I had to wipe a drive that had OpenSUSE on it to install elementary OS.  It SHOULD have worked by booting from the USB, but it didn't despite all the fiddling around with the BIOS.  I've found this on all kinds of distros.  I've had the same USB work on one computer and not another.

In short, and assuming you have exhausted the options in your BIOS, wipe the destination drive and try again.

Comment: Trust me, i've tried multiple times to wipe the entire USB drive and re-burned it. It just boots straight into elementaryOS

Comment: I meant the NVME.  Wipe that before you try to install on it.